# Cant access node.js/express API from Vue.js app on same docker network

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, nginx, axios

I am creating a web architecture with Vue.JS, a node.js / express backend and a mongoDB database. All is docked in separate containers but on the same subnet.

Dockers config files :
docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  backend:
    container_name: WESCANADMINBACK
    image: "node:latest"
    depends_on:
      - db
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    volumes:
      - /home/***/***/data/backend:/home/node/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://172.0.43.9:27017/wescan
      - APP_PORT=8080
    expose:
      - "8080"
    command: "node app.js"
    networks:
      adminNet:
        ipv4_address: 172.0.43.8

  db:
    container_name: WESCANADMINDB
    image: mongo:4.0
    restart: always
    networks:
            adminNet:
              ipv4_address: 172.0.43.9


  frontend:
    container_name: WESCANADMIN
    build:
      context: /home/***/***/data
    volumes:
      - /home/***/***/data:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - BACKEND_URL=http://172.0.43.8/wescan
    networks:
            adminNet:
              ipv4_address: 172.0.43.10

networks:
    adminNet:
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
        config:
           - subnet: 172.0.43.0/24
```

Dockerfile (frontend)

```
FROM node:latest as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:alpine as production-build
COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I tried to send request from my server to ip adress of the API and it's works. However, when the request is sent from the web application with Axios it is impossible to access to API.

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
    crossDomain: true,
    baseURL: 'http://172.0.43.8:8080/api'
})
export default instance
```

I tried a lot of things from the web like `ENV HOST 0.0.0.0` in Dockerfile or `crossDomain: true` in axios parameters but nothing.
cya

Comment: The Vue application probably runs in a browser; even if it's being served from a container, it doesn't actually run in a container, and it can't access the Docker-internal host names or IP addresses.  I'd suggest setting up a `proxy_pass` route in your Nginx configuration to forward to the API service, and using a path-only URL `/api` in your browser application.

Comment: Yes I suspected that the request comes from the client accessing the application but I didn't want to come to this solution of making the API public for machine to machine. Unfortunately, I don't think I have any other solution than this one with a javascript web application.

Comment: Your browser application is making a call from the public Internet to your API; you have to make the API public for this to work.  There's nothing Docker can do to help this out.